# Lucene: how to keep lithuanian language symbols in StandardAnalyzer?

Tags: utf-8, lucene, stop-words

I have done my own analyzer for unneccessary data and stop-words removal with Lucene (version 4.3.0).

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43, new CharArraySet(Version.LUCENE_43, stopWords, true));
```

Everything works as expected, but my language is 
lithuanian, so i would like to keep lithuanian language symbols: 'ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽąčęėįšųūž'. The main problem that lithuanian language don't have own analyzer.. 
At the moment, words are truncated (without ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽąčęėįšųūž symbols). 
Any suggestions how to override the format method/ keep these symbols ? I don't need the stemming tool.

Comment: `StandardAnalyzer` is not likely to be the problem here.  It supports many different languages' character sets (as specified by [UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.. Yes `StandardAnalyzer` is not the problem here, I was reading data in wrong unicode format (`UTF-8`), which was written in `Windows-1257`. This produced unneccessary symbols, which were interpreted as rubbish. So changing it to the right unicode solved this isssue :)